# Work done by our body in Cycling and Walking

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, newtonian-gravity, work

Q. Why does Cycling consumes less body energy than walking?

Any logical explanation? I've been trying to seek any logical explanation for this question for few days! But why does Cycling consumes less body energy with more displacement, are there any factors related to this? Is it because of gravity or friction or work done and whatever! It is fair in the cases of motor  vehicles because much of the work is done by engine! But a cycle does not have any engine, then who provides the additional work required to displace ourselves from one point to other?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: A simple cause might be because of static and rolling friction.

Comment: Related/Duplicate https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/283305/